# Labels for each bibliography entry within an entry set with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I have a few references that consist of several bibliography entries that are grouped via `biblatex`'s command `\defbibentryset` (using `biber` as backend). The standard behaviour of `biblatex` is to seperate the entries by a semicolon without any further labelling. I wonder wether there is a possibility to assign a label (arabic or roman numbers or letters) to each of the entries so that it looks like

[1] a) bibliography entry; b) bibliograhpy entry; c) ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes the `entrysetcount` field really comes in handy. :-)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{bibentrysetcount}{\mknumalph{#1})\addhighpenspace}
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \printfield[bibentrysetcount]{entrysetcount}%
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{A01}

\defbibentryset{set}{B02,C03}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

EDIT: `\addhighpenspace` discourages line breaks after the label, but does not forbid them. As for the format of `entrysetcount`: I should have used the `bibentrysetcount` format -- example corrected.

EDIT 2: Another advantage of using the `bibentrysetcount` format is that one can drop the `\iffieldundef` test -- example corrected again.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works quite nice. Just for the sake of completeness: would you add the package-option `backend=biber` to `biblatex`? Since I'm pretty new to this forum I don't know yet wether I should edit another person's answer to add something like this or not. I have two little questions: Can I controle which labels are used (numbers, letters,...)? What did you use the `\addhighpenspace` command for?

Comment: @Philipp: Good catch -- I forgot that biber is necessary here; I always enable it in my configuration file `biblatex.cfg`.